# Mongodb update function only works when .then() is included

Tags: node.js, mongodb, increment

I am looking to increment a field in mongodb every time a request is made. My update function only works when .then() is included after the function call and I don't understand why.

Code is working, but i'm interested in understanding why I need to include the .then().  Adapter function is called either way, but update only appears in db when .then() is included after function call.

update function:

```
updateRequestCount: (id) => {
    return Entry.updateOne({id: id }, { '$inc': { requestCount: 1 } });
}
```

works:

```
updateRequestCount(request.query.id)
.then();
```

does not work:

```
updateRequestCount(request.query.id);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `Model.updateOne()` or any other CRUD method of a Model on Mongoose it returns a `Query` object which has a `then()` method that will execute the query and return a `Promise`.

So the query is not immediately executed when you call `updateOne()` but only when you call `then()` on the returned Query object.

Alternatively you can pass a callback function to `updateOne()` in this case, the query IS immediately executed and you don't have to call `then()`:

```
updateRequestCount: (id) => {
  return Entry.updateOne({id: id }, { '$inc': { requestCount: 1 } }, err => {
    // ...
  });
}
```